# Merging multiple child managed object contexts

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, merge, managedobjectcontext

In my iOS application, I am attempting to sync core data with a web back end. I want to use a separate background managed object context for the sync so I can keep my main context free to accept changes from the ui while the sync is processing. Both contexts are children of my write-to-disk context as per this blog post http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/.

**My question is, how can I merge both children contexts before I save to disk?**

If I subscribe to contextDidSaveNotifications, I can merge the contexts using

```
[mainContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:syncFinishedNotification];
```

but according to the documentation...
"This method refreshes any objects which have been updated in the other context, faults in any newly-inserted objects, and invokes deleteObject:: on those which have been deleted."

I don't want to refresh the updated objects and lose changes made to the mainContext, but rather merge both change sets.

I am new to multi-context core data, so I may be thinking of this in the wrong way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Merging changes in Core Data is always a process of taking changes in one managed object context and then applying them to another context. If both contexts might acquire new changes at the same time, the merge is affected by the context's merge policy. If there are no *conflicting* changes, there's nothing to worry about. If there might be, though, you'll need to choose an appropriate merge policy.

The default value if you do nothing is `NSErrorMergePolicyType`, which means that saving changes would fail after merging changes. You almost certainly don't want that. But there are other predefined policies to choose from. `NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType` is often a good choice here, because gives priority to unsaved conflicting changes. So if the sync context makes conflicting changes to an object the user is editing, the user's changes are preserved. There are a few other canned options. If none of them fit, you can always subclass `NSMergePolicy` and do whatever you like. That's rarely necessary, though.

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I was looking for. After reading up a bit more, it seems that I don't even need to use mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification. If I save the child contexts, all the changes will be merged into the parent using the NSMergePolicy that I specify. Is this a correct understanding?

Comment: @adamF I too felt your understanding is correct after go through couple of discussions in stack overflow although no justified/documented. "don't even need to use mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification. If I save the child contexts, all the changes will be merged into the parent using the NSMergePolicy that I specify" Did you confirm if our assumption is correct?